# What commands to provide for zipping files based on Date range and also include timestamp

Tags: bash, zip

I am creating a zip file of some files (image files), but need to limit it such that only the latest files are added to the zip file. I need files that are more than 2 days old. Exact time is not relevant.

This is what I have been doing, but how do I limit it based on date? This is Linux and is run from a batch .sh file..

```
zip -r /destination_path/media_backup.zip /from_path/media
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` in conjunction with `zip`.

As indicated in `man zip`, use option `-@`.

```
find . -mtime +2 -print | zip source -@
```

A single `-` can also be used instead of `-@`.

`-x` and `-i` can be used to read the files in include form a list file as well.

See man for other details.